# Latin characters break XML Post Request in Java

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

I have an XML POST request that works, until I change a field to include Latin UTF-8 characters such as "Î". I receive a 400 Bad Response from the service.

Both of these requests work in the Google Chrome extension Postman.

I am assuming this has something to do with the way Java encodes characters or reads datastreams. Below is my code, including the relevant libraries. How can solve this? Thanks!

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


import net.valutec.ws.*;


public class CardCallbacks extends ValutecWSCallbackHandler  {
    private void sendInfoToMaropost(GiftCard please) throws IOException {

        URL serverUrl = new URL(TARGET_URL + API_KEY);
        URLConnection urlConnection = serverUrl.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection hcon = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
        System.out.println(dont.getBarcode());
        try {


            hcon.setReadTimeout(10000);
            hcon.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            hcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
            hcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            hcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            hcon.setDoInput(true);
            hcon.setDoOutput(true);

            String body = 

                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<record>" + 
                        "  <orderlineid>fakeorderid</orderlineid>" + 
                        "  <encoded-barcode>Î</encoded-barcode>" +
                           //the request that doesn't work
                "</record>";    

            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(hcon.getOutputStream());

            output.write(body.getBytes());
            output.flush();

            int responseCode = hcon.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode);
            if(responseCode == 200) {

            }
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(hcon.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }



            System.out.println(response);

            in.close();

        }
        finally {
            hcon.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I've found the solution. This helped: [Unicode Characters](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)
This was the needed edit:

```
output.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've found the solution. This helped: Unicode Characters This was the needed edit:

```
output.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The default encoding for the class is "ISO 8859-1". I didn't figure out how to get "response" formatted to UTF-8 so that still returns with the wrong characters.